# Invalid parameter when setting an image

Tags: c#, winforms, image, exception, .net-2.0

I'm running a .NET 2.0 program on many computers. On one I had this error occurring repeatedly until I reset the application.

```
 //line below was throwing the exception
 this.myButton.BackgroundImage = global::myNamespace.Properties.Resources.myImage;
```

Exception:

```
 ExceptionType: ArgumentException
 Message: Parameter is not valid.
 Source: System.Drawing
 StackTrace:    at System.Drawing.Image.get_Flags()
     at System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.IsImageTransparent(Image backgroundImage)
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_BackgroundImageLayout(ImageLayout value)
```

The resource exists and it works fine once reset. Can anyone provide any insight as to might be happening?

Comment: Possibly the image file got locked by something? Virus scanner pops into mind...

Comment: Yip, agreed... disable anti-virus

Comment: @CodingGorilla I'll try that if I can replicate.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to examine real-time activity on the file, and which processes might be locking it. Add a Filter where the Path is the name of the image/resource file; this should quickly show if anything is monkeying around with the file behind your back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a 6 year old post! Ran into the same error today, and it took me far longer to fix than it should have. I was actually disposing my image control on startup, so I obviously couldn't adjust its background image on run-time. Might as well double check for that if you're here.